# Maven - Write property to file

Tags: java, maven

I am using jsonpath-maven-plugin to read my package.json and set a property with the current version read from the file.

I am wondering how I can write the property "package.json.version" to a properties file, so the Java class can read the property file and pickup the version set in the properties file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ca.szc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonpath-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>read-devdependencies</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <file>src/main/npm/package.json</file>
                <properties>
                    <package.json.version>$.version</package.json.version>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've been trying with the Apache Maven Resources plugin but it doesn't seem to pickup my property.. Same for the Properties Maven Plugin

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't showed what you tried that didn't work, but this has worked for me in the past: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried.. all properties defined in the POM and profiles were picked up except the one set by the plugin